# youtube data API not resetting quota

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

since 3 days the youtube Data API v3 keeps returning the same quota exceeded errors. I made some changes to drastically reduce the number of calls to the API yesterday, hoping it would reset at midnight pacific time today, but no such luck. Could somebody please look into this. The project ID is (removed), project number is (removed).

Thank you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack overflow is not Google support we cant check your project.  Please contact Google support

Comment: Welcome to stack please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  If you have a programming question.  Please edit your question include your code and describe any issues you are having with your current solution error messages for example.

Comment: DalmTo according to google/youtube https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/support this is the youtube API support

Comment: Just because a third party company chooses to put a link that on their website that links to Stack Overflow does not mean we can help you.   We are not Google support we do not have access to their systems.  You need to contact Google for help with Google Quota errors.   We can only help with programming issues.  Again If you have a programming question. Please edit your question include your code and describe any issues you are having with your current solution error messages for example.

Comment: Please be patient and allow the Google engineers that monitor this forum to answer my question. I understand nobody else here will be able to and I'm fine with that. Thank you.

Comment: I have been here for eight years.  I have never seen a Google engineer for YouTube answer a question on stack overflow.   I have actual never seen any Google engineer respond to a question about quota as its not their responsibility.

Comment: While you wait why dont you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: @TotallyFuzzy If you need response from Google engineer - then contact Google. StackOverflow is not Google support forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@TotallyFuzzy I am having same issue yesterday and when I looked into quota the daily limit was set to 0 in my google admin console and there was no way edit,
[image]

so in the end I removed and recreate the youtube API in developer console

that fixed the problem for me, here is the screenshot of new youtube API quota

[image]

Comment: yep, same here, in IAM control panel quota has been reset to 0. No notification, no email, no response to my asking support on youtube devs forums. WTF. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @TotallyFuzzy If that's works for you, please select this as accepted answer, it will help others - Thanks

Comment: Kashif Naseem: How do I do that, select this as accepted answer? I don't see that option anywhere? Anyway it was the perfect answer, we're up and running again.

Comment: @TotallyFuzzy https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20accept%20an%20answer%3A,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.

Comment: @KashifNaseem can you elaborate on how you "recreate" the API? You mean API key? If so, I did that, and no change for me... cycled the API to disable and enable as well. same thing.

Comment: @Valkyrurr not API key, just create the new YouTube App.